# Initializing instance variables via Get & Set vs Constructor

Tags: java, constructor, properties, get, set

I have a simple question yet confusing one.
Lets say I have a class with its own fields, I want to initialize them in the Main class, but I know I can use "Get and Set" methods to do that, and also it's possible to use the class's constructor and achieve the same result.

My question is, what is a better or a more appropriate approach to address this kind of situation? what is the difference between them, and what are the pros and cons of doing one over the other?

Thanks, I'll appreciate a good answer :)

Comment: of course you can, if the constructor takes the fields then it enforces that **all** fields are passed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a constructor to initialize a global variable then you can do it only at the time when you will create an object.Think of a case where you might to change the value of a variable very often in that case you need not to create a new object to do that just call the getter and setter methods and thy will do the job for you .
Constructors will automatically do the job only once when you will declare it but getter and setter method could do that job again and again as and when you need.

Comment: So, in other words, things I know for sure that won't change once an object is being created at runtime, I can assign using the object's class constructor (Kinda like default values right?), and things that needs to get changed during the runtime of the program, I better use properties right?

Answer (score 1):

In essence: you should only provide setters when you rely on frameworks that will need them. For example: when parsing serialized data from JSON files, many frameworks want that you have setter methods; which they find/use via reflection.

In general:

- make your fields final
- use the constructor to initialize them
- avoid providing setters if possible

Background: good OO is about *encapsulation* and *hiding of implementation*. Fields should be "private business" of objects; nobody else outside should need to know about them. Exposing setters allows for all kinds of misuse later on.

Answer (score 1):

**Object Oriented Design Concepts**

The concept of a *Constructor* in pure *OOD* is to ensure that an instance of a class is in a valid state after construction.

Ensuring this invariant, in pure *OOD* all method calls of an instance should preserve the validity of the instance state.

**Framework Concepts**

Frameworks often rely on a default *Constructor* to be able to create an instance of a class.

Due to support readability and flexibility of instance configuration, frameworks often require *Setters* to initialize the state of the instance.

To mimic the invariant after construction, some frameworks support *post-creation* callback methods which should validate the final state of the instance after creation and initialization.

**Consequences**

By providing a default constructor and *Setters* your instance are all mutable even in cases when they would be not.

Your instances may be in an invalid state when not created and validated by your framework (e.g. when created in unit-testing in a setup method).

**Best practices using both worlds**

Try to avoid default constructors and *Setters* for classes which require parameters to establish a valid internal state.

Try to define as many fields *final* as possible.

If you must provide *Setters* support only constructors which take all required parameters reusing their *Setters* to establish their initial internal state. The *Setters* should enforce all required rules before changing the internal state.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was more understandable :)

Answer (score 0):

> On my point of view initializing in constructor advantage

-easy initialization of private fields and don't need to use setter method

> initializing in setter method advantage

-unpopulated your constructor for cleaner and easy to understand constructor if you have an if-else,looping to do etc.

> getter method

it is used to return values so that you can use it in e.g. arithmetic operations or test conditions etc

Answer (score 0):

Finally got my question answered.
Short as possible: Whenever I need to initialize an instance variable with a value that I know for sure that won't change during runtime, I should be using the constructor.
But, for values that needs to be changed during runtime, Setters and Getters comes to the rescue and help you initialize mutable values.

Hope that helps.
Credit goes to: java fan.